# After starting the android emulator its window remains stagnant

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

After setting up the emulator and creating an android virtual device. The Emulator launches the device but the screen remains static, not showing any icons and launching of application on the virtual device fails with the error:

Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.[application launch activity]" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

[screen of the virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnkEa.png)

the details of the device is as follows:

Name: Galaxy_Nexus_API_24_AMD

CPU/ABI: ARM (arm64-v8a)

Path: C:\Users\OPEYEMI.android\avd\Galaxy_Nexus_API_24_AMD.avd

Target: default [] (API level 24)

Skin: galaxy_nexus

SD Card: 512 MB

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Galaxy Nexus

hw.lcd.width: 720

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 24

tag.id: default

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Galaxy Nexus API 24 AMD

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1024

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 1

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1280

vm.heapSize: 80

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-24\default\arm64-v8a\

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Galaxy_Nexus_API_24_AMD

hw.lcd.density: 320

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:fcb1c44f60d9172bb27b44fdd821eed1

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display:

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Answer (score 0):

[image: Emulator]

Uninstall and then reInstall the Emulator.